# How do I INSERT info from one table into its LINK table?

Tags: sql, asp.net, hyperlink, insert-into

I'm trying to build an asp.net application, where I have three tables.

```
tblRoute
tblHalte
tblHalteRoute
```

I want to insert a routeID into tblHalteRoute and for every routeID multiple halteID's

TblRoute has the needed fields (routeID(1) &
 allHaltes[halteID1,halteID2,halteID3])
--> so Every route has multiple Haltes that I can access by parsing the allHaltes field and using the IDS.

What I want to do is update tblHalteRoute like this:

```
tblRoute.routeID(1), tblRoute.allHaltes(halteID1)
tblRoute.routeID(1), tblRoute.allHaltes(halteID2)
tblRoute.routeID(1), tblRoute.allHaltes(halteID3)
```

inserting these values into the tblHalteRoute .. I'm really not sure on where to look or how to start, I tried using SUBquerys with an Insert before a select, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to pivot data - eg

```
Route 1 Halte 1
Route 1 Halte 2
Route 1 Halte 3

-->

Route 1 Halte 1 Halte 2 Halte 3
```

I'm also assuming you mean LINQ not LINK (as in the data access mechanism)

If this is the case, you could write a function that does something like:

```
Dim MyNewRow = New tblHalteRoute
Dim Routes = MyRoutes.Where(function(x) x.RouteId = 1).OrderBy(function(x) x.RouteId)

MyNewRow.Route1 = Routes.First.id
MyNewRow.Route2 = Routes.Skip(1).First.id
MyNewRow.Route£ = Routes.Skip(2).First.id
```

It's worth nnoting that you're making an assumption that your Route table will have more Id fields than there are Ids = This may be a valid assumption for your app but even if it is, it feels dangerous to me - I'd suggest you store this properly (ie keep it relational) and then just `For Each` each row as required - then there's no limit to the number of Ids available.

Comment: Hej Basiclife, thanks for the swift reply. With LINK table I ment a cross reference table (connecting two tables through their IDS if I'm correct?) I must admit your answer is not entirely clear to me (not that experience). I'll try to recap one Route has many Haltes (stored in the field alleHaltes(divided by ,s) but one halte can also have different routes. so If I make a new route with ID(1) and halte (1)(2) and(3), I would have to update the routeID and halteID from the cross reference table like this. routeID1 + halteID1, routeID1 + halteID2, routeID1 + halteID3